# Where to get Windows UEFI Secure Boot public keys (DB etc.) from

Tags: windows-10, secure-boot

I have an old laptop which was manufactured before Windows 8. It didn't have MS keys inside. I successfully generated keys for Linux and enabled secure boot in BIOS but, as expected, I cannot boot Windows any longer.

Where can I get necessary keys for Windows 10 from?

Answer (score 0):

The links are on [Microsoft page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747883.aspx). For whatever reason I was unable to enroll DB except in Setup Mode.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the 2022/2023 updated page, you can find download links on it, both 2011 and 2023 keys. It says Windows 11, but it works for 10, too. I tested both the 2011 and the 2023 keys, only the DB key requires the 2011 version for Windows 10. For the other types of keys, the 2023 version also worked for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-secure-boot-key-creation-and-management-guidance

Comment: 1) "(...) do your best to verify what you are suggesting works for the operating system in question. ": I now tested on Windows 10 and it works. Updated the text.
2) "(...) different than the ones offered in 2024" - The link I posted contains both 2023 and 2011 keys.
3) "(...) the author, already submitted this answer" - It's a different link. The one from my answer is newer and has updated info, that's why I added a new answer.

For these reasons, I kindly ask you to reconsider your downvoting. Thanks.